# How to remove duplicate values in specific column without removing related row

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, plotly

Want to remove duplicate values in specific column without deleting the rows related with duplicate column values as below example:

```
Input
-----
    Date    Market      Quantity
4/2/2018    Indonesia   1000
4/2/2018    Australia   500
4/2/2018    India       300
4/2/2018    USA         500
4/2/2018    Germany     200
5/2/2018    India       400
5/2/2018    Japan       400
5/2/2018    Russia      457
6/2/2018    Austria     260
6/2/2018    Swiss       700
6/2/2018    USA         1200
6/2/2018    Indonesia   400


output
------
    Date    Market      Quantity
4/2/2018    Indonesia   1000
            Australia   500
            India       300
            USA         500
            Germany     200
5/2/2018    India       400
            Japan       400
            Russia      457
6/2/2018    Austria     260
            Swiss       700
            USA         1200
            Indonesia   400
```

And if possible , how to plot a graph(bar/column) for same output(something like given)?
[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBnuH.png)

Comment: Where is the trade quantity column?  I think it is better to keep the original format for plotting.  If you really wanted `df1$Date[duplicated(df1$Date)] <- ""`

Comment: @akrun edited quantity

Comment: Why set them equal to "" instead of NA?

Comment: Take a look to this [plugin](https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories)

Comment: It would be easier to do `facet_wrap` i.e. `library(ggplot2); ggplot(Input, aes(x = Market, y = Quantity)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + facet_wrap(~ Date)`

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to comments but I don't have rights yet...

I don't think you actually want to change the data, but as a few mentioned in the comments there are easy ways to do that.

If you're just trying to show the multi-dimensional data in plotly and you're just not familiar with the library syntax try the code below...

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c('2018/04/02','2018/04/02','2018/04/02','2018/04/02','2018/04/02','2018/05/02','2018/05/02','2018/05/02','2018/06/02','2018/06/02','2018/06/02','2018/06/02'),
  Market = c('Indonesia','Australia','India','USA','Germany','India','Japan','Russia','Austria','Swiss','USA','Indonesia'),
  Quantity = c(1000,500,300,500,200,400,400,457,260,700,1200,400),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

plotly::ggplotly(
      ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x=Market, y=Quantity)) +
        ggplot2::geom_col(ggplot2::aes(fill=Market))+
        ggplot2::facet_grid(~Date,scale='free_x') +
        ggthemes::theme_tufte()
      )
```

Comment: Yup,if we are plotting data,it is fine but again for filtering purpose i asked the question. Again,could we somehow plot the same data with same format in highcharts?  Thanks for help :)